# Intent chooser is created exactly three times in UncaughtException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am creating my own UncaughtException behavior. I want to send an email with the report so when the UncaughtException is handled, I want to create a chooser and let the user choose their email client.

When I do this, after calling the Intent, I have to kill the process. But killing the process makes the Intent chooser to be created three times instead of just once. What should I do differently?

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
}

@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    MyLog.w("[BaseActivity]::[uncaughtException]");
    ex.printStackTrace();

    StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
    ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
    final String message = errors.toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"my@email.address"});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ERROR: Controller");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    try {
        MyLog.i("[starting chooser]::[%s]",System.currentTimeMillis());
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.msg_send_action_msg)));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.msg_err_no_email_client, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

}
```

}

Comment: It may not fix things, but you should probably call `finish()` after `startActivity`

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek funny but you may have solved my problem, haha :)) I have added finish() after startActivity() and the chooser was created just once. Will do more testing and get back!

Comment: Yep, it really helped! If you make an answer for this question, I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `finish()` after `startActivity`